# Click event for DataGridCheckBoxColumn

Tags: wpf, events, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` in a WPF form with a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`, but I did not find any click event, Checked and unchecked for it...

Are these events available for the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`? If not please suggest some workaround I could use.

Answer (score 27):

Quoted from William Han's answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/wpf/thread/9e3cb8bc-a860-44e7-b4da-5c8b8d40126d

It simply adds an event to the column. It is a good simple solution.

> Perhaps you can use `EventSetter` as example below:
>
> Markup:
>
> ```
> <Window x:Class="DataGridCheckBoxColumnTest.MainWindow"
>         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridCheckBoxColumnTest"
>         Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
>     <Window.Resources>
>         <local:People x:Key="People"/>
>     </Window.Resources>
>     <Grid>
>         <DataGrid ItemsSource="{StaticResource People}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
>             <DataGrid.Columns>
>                 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name"/>
>                 <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=LikeCar}" Header="LikeCar">
>                     <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
>                         <Style>
>                             <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="OnChecked"/>
>                         </Style>
>                     </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
>                 </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
>             </DataGrid.Columns>
>         </DataGrid>
>     </Grid>
> </Window>
> ```
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.Windows;
>
> namespace DataGridCheckBoxColumnTest
> {
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
>     /// </summary>
>     public partial class MainWindow : Window
>     {
>         public MainWindow()
>         {
>             InitializeComponent();
>         }
>
>         void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>         {
>             throw new NotImplementedException();
>         }
>     }
> }
>
>
> namespace DataGridCheckBoxColumnTest
> {
>     public class Person
>     {
>         public Person(string name, bool likeCar)
>         {
>             Name = name;
>             LikeCar = likeCar;
>         }
>         public string Name { set; get; }
>         public bool LikeCar { set; get; }
>     }
> }
>
> using System.Collections.Generic;
>
> namespace DataGridCheckBoxColumnTest
> {
>     public class People : List<Person>
>     {
>         public People()
>         {
>             Add(new Person("Tom", false));
>             Add(new Person("Jen", false));
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Note for anyone who comes across this in the future: a `CheckBox.Checked` event will only fire when the checkbox is set to *checked*, not when it's clicked in general.  If you want this event, you'll almost certainly also want to bind `CheckBox.Unchecked` to the same handler!

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on the DataGridCell concept noted above, this is what we used to get it working.

...XAML...

```
    <DataGrid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="dgMissingNames" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TheMissingChildren}" Style="{StaticResource NameListGrid}" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource NameListCol}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="theCheckbox" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                            
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SKU}" Header="Album" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" "/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Pronunciation}" Header="Pronunciation" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

TheMissingChildren is an ObservableCollection object that contains the list of data elements including a boolean field "Checked" that we use to populate the datagrid.

The SelectionChanged code here will set the checked boolean in the underlying TheMissingChildren object and fire off a refresh of the items list.  That ensures that the box will get checked off & display the new state no matter where you click on the row.   Clicking the checkbox or somewhere in the row will toggle the check on/off.

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid ThisGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    CheckedMusicFile ThisMusicfile = (CheckedMusicFile)ThisGrid.SelectedItem;
    ThisMusicfile.Checked = !ThisMusicfile.Checked;
    ThisGrid.Items.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<wpf:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Cool?" Width="40" Binding="{Binding IsCool}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this.

```
partial class SomeAwesomeCollectionItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property);
    }

    private bool _IsSelected;
    public bool IsSelected { get { return _IsSelected; } set { _IsSelected = Value; OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected"); } }
}
```

Then in XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeAwesomeCollection"} SelectionMode="Single">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
        <!--Note that you will probably need to base on other style if you have stylized your DataGridRow-->
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <!--More Columns-->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

One note with this approach, however, is you may run into issues with virtualization and checked items not clearing (not sure, haven't tested with SelectionMode="Single").  If that is the case, the simplest workaround I have found to work is to turn virtualization off, but perhaps there is a better way to get around that particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in xml

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="" IsThreeState="False" Binding="{Binding isCheck, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

And in c#

```
    public partial class UploadWindow : Window
    {
     ObservableCollection<Items> pl = new ObservableCollection<Items>();
    
      class Items
      {
        public bool isCheck { get; set; }
      }

      public UploadWindow(Dictionary<string, object> ipDictionary)
      {
        InitializeComponent();
        GridView1.ItemsSource = pl;
      }
     }
```

In my case, I need to find all checked checkboxes

```
var allChecked = pl.Where(x => x.isCheck == true);
```

Comment: This answer "NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" makes you my new best friend forever :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to add the event to your style you can also do it this way.

```
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="name" Header="name?" Binding="{Path=Name}"
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                        <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="Checked"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>eckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```