# Add attached event to DataGridColumn

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to use the DataGridCheckBoxColumn in a grid and I noticed it has no events for checked or unchecked, for some reason.

I was trying to add attached events to this by creating a custom CBColumn class that inherits DataGridCheckBoxColumn.

The problem I am running into is that I am not sure how to add the handler to the exposed property since DataGridCheckBoxColumn is not derived from UIElement.

Therefore AddHandler and RemoveHandler are not available in this code block:

```
 public event RoutedEventHandler Checked
    {
        add { AddHandler(CheckedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(CheckedEvent, value); }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to do this? I have looked all over with no luck.

EDIT: I am using MVVM, so I need to avoid Code Behind if possible.

Answer (score 0):

[Click event for DataGridCheckBoxColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759779/click-event-for-datagridcheckboxcolumn)

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=LikeCar}" Header="LikeCar">
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="OnChecked"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I am doing this in MVVM. I tried doing it this way with a Binding on the Handler property, but it doesn't work. That's why I wanted to override DataGridCheckBoxColumn and use an attached event.

Comment: I should also add that using Binding on Handler property throws null reference exception.

Comment: So your binding does not fire. Are you able to hit a break point when you select the item? I will try to get this to work in MVVM and post my findings.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is another solution in code. This is really rough, but it demonstrates the checked box and show a number values of what is checked in a text box.**

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridCheckBoxItemTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DataGridCheckBoxItemTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:DataGridTestVM />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              Margin="10">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Test Checked" Binding="{Binding S}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Text="{Binding Test, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
             Height="39" 
             Margin="20,244,0,0" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Width="237"/>
</Grid>
```

```
namespace DataGridCheckBoxItemTest
{
 public class DataGridTestVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
   ObservableCollection<Source> source;
   Source s;
   int test;

public DataGridTestVM()
{
  source = new ObservableCollection<Source>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    s = new Source();
    s.test = i;
    source.Add(s);
  }
}

public ObservableCollection<Source> Source
{
  get
  {
    return source;
  }

  set
  {
    source = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("Source");
  }
}

public int Test
{
  get
  {
    return test;
  }

  set
  {
    test = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("Test");
  }
}

public Source Selected
{
  get
  {
    return s;
  }

  set
  {
    s = value;
    Test = s.test;
    OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
  }
}

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
   {
     if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
     {
       this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
     }
   }
 }

 public class Source
 {
   public int test;
 }
}
```

Comment: So does this help or did you solve this on your own. If so, mark this as resolved. thanks

Comment: I really wanted to tap into a checked/unchecked commands. But I decided to go a different route.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just reverting to a DataGridTemplateColumn and using the checkbox control in there. Didn't seem like there was a way to do what I wanted.