# How to iterate through all checkboxes of a datagridcheckboxcolumn

Tags: c#, wpf, events, checkbox, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with three columns, including a DataGridCheckBoxColumn.  Based on whether the DataGrid is visible, I want to set an event for each CheckBox in the DataGridCheckBoxColumn.  I have defined an event for IsVisibleChanged.

```
void DataGrid_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;

    if (dg.IsVisible == false)
        return;

    // ?????
}
```

What I need to do is access every CheckBox in the DataGridCheckBoxColumn and define the same handler for the Checked and Unchecked events of each CheckBox.  No rows will be added while the program is running.

I'm sure there are multiple ways, but I haven't found one yet.  While I would prefer the most efficient code, I would accept any working answer.

Comment: Looks like this sort of thing has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759779/click-event-for-datagridcheckboxcolumn

Comment: Personally I'd TwoWay bind the DataGridCheckBoxColumn to boolean properties in a view model, then no need for a click event handler - it's just done by the set/get of the property

Comment: @IanofOz, if you're referring to the checked answer in 759779, I don't see much of an answer, except "use CommandBindings"; could you please elaborate.  If you're referring to the answer from IFink, the column is already bound to a property of a model; the checkboxes are not toggles for other functionality within the application.

Comment: If the columns are already bound to the view model, what more are you hoping to get from a CheckBox handler? And from the linked answer, I'd actually prefer the last solution - from Kent Boogaart